# How can I skip JRE code when debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When debugging in Eclipse, I step into (F5) a statement such as the following,

```
encryptedBytes = LightWeightEncryptor.encrypt(messageBytes, password.toCharArray());
```

the debugger steps into JRE method String.toCharArray(), but I want it to skip that and step into my own code, LightWeightEncryptor.encrypt.

I get tired of having to step out of the JRE code and step back into my own. I've seen lots of ways to step into JRE code, but I can't find a way to avoid it.

Comment: place a breakpoint after this line, and run debug.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try Eclipse menu : Window -> Preferences -> Java|Debug|Step Filtering.

Toggle "Use Step Filters", you may choose the step filters from the checkbox list.

E.g. check "java.*", then the JRE method String.xxx() will be skipped.

Comment: I think I love you. This is an awesome tip, and I wish I had this years ago.

Comment: @kshen, do you know how to do this in netbeans. I can't seem to find this option in the menus

Comment: @peeskillet, I am not familiar with netbeans. However, I would suggest you to file a Stackoverflow question with the netbeans tag. Hope the netbeans community could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add types built on the fly, or types that you have dificulty to find going to:

**Debug Window**
[image]

Right click on desired class, click on **Filter Type**:
[image]

In next time your **Step Filter** will skip this type.