# Is there annotate a method in java (eclipse editor) so that the debugger always steps over it

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, annotations

I'm writing code with a lot of minor methods of the literally-can't-be-incorrect variety (e.g. one-line get/set methods for private fields), and while debugging, I don't want to accidently step into one of them because that changes the stack which resets the focus on my fields and variables.

Is there any sort of @ annotation or something like that which will tell the debugger, "if you're told to step into this function, step over it instead"?

Comment: Maybe sth like this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850410/how-can-i-skip-jre-code-when-debugging-in-eclipse   You could just add to filter your methods which you want to skip from debugging

Answer (score 0):

```
F5 – “Step Into”
F6 – “Step Over”
F7 – “Step Return”
F8 – “Resume”
Ctrl+Shift+B – “Toggle Breakpoint”
Ctrl+Shift+I – “Inspect”
```

This is all I can find for you. Debugging depends on IDE(in this case eclipse) setting so I sure with you there's no `@annotation` on source code that can archive your requirement.

Comment: But there might be some plugin for eclipse which can do that

Comment: Maybe I guess, but the point I want to show is no `@annotation` on source code can do that. The source code has nothing to do with the debugging's configuration/settings.